# Share Variables stored across PRIVATE modules

Tags: vba, excel

Who can advise me, I have 2 private modules where I have a value storred in module 1 e.g. TotalFoundIssues = 166. This value which is stored in module 1, I need to use in module 2, like if TotalFoundIssues is > 100 Do this ..... I see many solutions already but they do not work because they refer to global or public which I need to avoid.

Comment: This is from "Mastering VBA for Microsoft Office 2016":
"The Private keyword limits the scope of a macro - the area in which it can operate. Private scope makes the macro available to all procedures in the module that contains it, but not to procedures in other modules"

Comment: Let module 1 be a class, and instantiate an object within module 2.

Comment: If you need to share a value then maybe put it by itself in a non-private module?

Answer (score 1):

You can expose it through a read-only Public Property:

```
Private mTotalFoundIssues As Long

Public Property Get TotalFoundIssues() As Long
    TotalFoundIssues = mTotalFoundIssues
End Property
```